# Display the title of the current post in the text of wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I would like to display the title of the post somewhere in its body content. So somehow I need to enter either php or a shortcode in the main text field of the post in the cms to echo the title. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest will be to register a shortcode that returns `get_the_title()`.

Comment: That helped. I registered this shortcode `function gettitle_func($atts) {
return get_the_title();
}
add_shortcode('gettitle', 'gettitle_func');`
And with this `[gettitle]` in the content it displayed the current post title.